# Customize font-size with PhantomJS for Outlook mail server

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs, kibana-5, outlook-2016

I'm running server in Node.js that use PhantomJS webkit as non-browser service.
My purpose is to extract graphs/ data tables from Kibana dashboards, using snapshot URL, render it, and send it as base 64 mail content to Outlook server

My problem is that I can't custom font-size. Both in CSS file or in the body parameters for PhanthomJS markup file (it's the Email final markup)

The thing is that I can customize CSS properties for graphs, E.g. width & height, but all that refer to text I can't

Next is part of the function that takes part in the viewport:

```
page.property('viewportSize', { width: 7000, height: 5120, font: 100});
```

Any key that I'll put, won't make any change in the font - **font, fontSize, font-size**.

Also when trying to add CSS file the class from Kibana:

```
.tick text {font-size: 50px;}
```

Nothing happens (this class refer to the text over X axis in bar chart)

My incoming mail looks like this:

[image]

As it can see, the proportion between the graph and text are bad

**PhantomJS version: 2.1.16**

Any idea?

Comment: Give this a shot: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Hi @Will - tnx for the tip. I've tried it but the thing is that it's reading the css after the PhantomJS code so no effect. I need a markup for the PhantomJS function

Comment: Well..... I've tried to manipulate the DOM before the page is render. No change even when adding styling objects